# How do I need to change My OnClickListener to stop the currentSound and start the new One OnClick

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Hello I´m right now doing a free course at Udacity to build a translation app.
And there was the task, to get the ListItem of the ArrayList to play a Sound onClick. They said you could do this alone or with the tutorials. So I did it my own and skipped the tutorials which showed how to do it. 
Now I came back to the tutorials with my working code. 
And than they gave us another task. To release the resources with the OnStop Method and after the MediaPlayer has stopped playing. 
But I did the previous task not as them did in the tutorial. And now I´m stuck to complete the new task.

I have made an own Adapter "WordAdapter" and I have 4 activitys.

In the WordAdapter I made 2 global values:

private MediaPlayer play;
private int isPlaying;

In the @OverrideMethod
I set the value of isPlaying to 0;

```
isPlaying = 0;
```

and I created an OnClicklistener

```
private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener mOnCompletion = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        isPlaying = 0;
        releaseMediaPlayer();
    }
};
```

And I created an ImageButton width an OnClickListener

```
    ImageButton playIcon = (ImageButton) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.playIcon);
        int colorOfThePlayIcon = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), mColorResourceId);
        playIcon.setBackgroundColor(colorOfThePlayIcon);
        playIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                play = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), currentWord.getPlaySound());

                if (isPlaying == 1) {
                    play.stop();
                    play.reset();
                    play.create(getContext(), currentWord.getPlaySound());
                    play.start();
                    isPlaying = 1;

                }

                if (isPlaying == 0) {
                    play.start();
                    isPlaying = 1;
                }
                play.setOnCompletionListener(mOnCompletion);
            }
        });
```

than I have made a releaseMediaPlayerMethod:

```
public void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    if (play != null){
        play.release();
        play = null;
    }
}
```

than in the Activity I made an OnStop Method:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    WordAdapter stopSoundAndReleasIt = new WordAdapter(this);
    stopSoundAndReleasIt.releaseMediaPlayer();
}
```

So this code should release the resources of the MediaPlayer after the word finished playing. 
And when the activity is stopped after the user has leaved the app the resources should be released too.
And when I click on the playIcon while the MediaPlayer is playing a sound it should stop the current sound and start playing the new selected.
And if I´m leaving the App while the MediaPlayer is playing a sound it should stop the sound first and than release the resources.

But if I click on the playIcon the App doesn´t stop the current sound and start the new one. Its just playing both sounds. Or three sounds if I click three times.

And if I leave the App it doesn´t stop the current sound too.

So what do I need to change that it stops the current Sound onClick?

Comment: I think you should be creating the media player outside the `onClick(...)` method. As it is now, you're always calling `stop()` and `release()` on a newly created instance of `MediaPlayer`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But if I take the `.create` out of the `onClick(...)` method the app stops working when I click on the playIcon. 

And I think if the sound is not playing the `stop()` method is not called because the. isPlaying value is set to 0 when the app is created and through the onCompletion method.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code in the onClick Method and in the releaseMediaPlayer method. Now the playing sound stops and the new sound starts if I click two times on the play Icon.

```
public void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    // If the media player is not null, then it may be currently playing a sound.
    if (play != null) {
        // Regardless of the current state of the media player, release its resources
        // because we no longer need it.
        play.release();
        // Set the media player back to null. For our code, we've decided that
        // setting the media player to null is an easy way to tell that the media player
        // is not configured to play an audio file at the moment.
        play = null;
        Log.e("WordAdapter.this", "onStop");
    }
}

playIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            releaseMediaPlayer();
            play = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), currentWord.getPlaySound());
            play.start();
            play.setOnCompletionListener(mOnCompletion);
        }
    });
```

Now the only problem is, that it doesn´t calls the 'releaseMediaPlayer(...)' method if I hit the home button. And the actual sound doesn´t stops playing.

In the WordAdapter I have this code. That I can can call the releaseMediaPlayer method in the Activity.

```
public WordAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, 0, 0);
}
```

EDIT: I got the real Problem now the releaseMediaPlayer method is called how it should be but the

```
if(play != null) {}
```

is allways false when I call it from a activity. But I dont know why.